# OOP Session set with dynamic path

Tags: php, oop, session, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I am working on a project where I want to set a session dynamically.

I have a Class named Session with a method names Set:

```
class Session{

        public static function set($name, $value){

            $path = explode('/', $name);
            $count = count($path);

           $_SESSION[$path] = $value;

        }
}
```

I want the method 'Set' to be executed like this: `Session::set('mysql/host', '127.0.01')`

With that example it should set `$_SESSION['mysql']['host']` to '127.0.0.1'.

With the method as it is now it gives me an error that $path can't be an array.
How can I get the method to work the way I want it?

Sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm working on that, but have no time to show you now. Will post an answer in about 12 hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
   class Session{

    public static function set($name, $value){

        $path = explode('/', $name);
        $count = count($path);

       $_SESSION[$path[0]][$path[1]] = $value ;
     }
    }
```

function explode return array. first element -mysql, second -host.

Comment: Thx for the quick answer, but i want it to be dynamic, so that i can later us Session::set('num1/num2/num3', 'value'); So the $name can be longer than 2.

Comment: how much num do you have in name?

Comment: Well, I like to have it check automaticly, and not have a certain number. Is this possible or not? Otherwise I will just look for another way to achive my needs

Comment: sorry, now I don't know, how it is done. May be somebody will have you.